# Java code not executing after the Authentication popup appears on firefox[selenium webdriver]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am trying to automate window authentication pop up handling.

Whenever I get a URL using driver.get(url) I gets a authentication pop-up.
I tried AutoIT scrip to automate authentication of popup which is working with internet explorer but not with firefox.
The code after the popup appears is not executing, so I think thats the reason AutoIT script is not working.

Code:

```
        driver.get("xyz.com/");  // authentication pop-up appears after this line
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("done"); // This line is not executing.
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "C://Users//basicauth_ff.exe");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Script: 
         `WinWaitActive("Authentication Required","","10")
            If WinExists("Authentication Required") Then
            Send("userid{TAB}")
            Send("password{Enter}")
            EndIf`

Comment: Can we get the url (if it's the xyz.com one it's a browser setting that's your problem) or the code for the pop up, you may not need AutoIT.

Comment: popup is displayed as the url is loaded but after that nothing happens because the code after loading of url is not executed

Comment: if i use the same code for internet explorer, i can see the url being loaded, popup displayed and username and password being entered in popup.

Comment: Can you describe the pop up as I cannot replicate the issue in IE, FF or Chrome.

Comment: browser popup which asks for username and password with submit and cancel buttons.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it it is a Firefox browser setting issue. You should either change your default settings for Firefox, or alternatively you can do it by setting preferences as follows:

```
FirefoxProfile fxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
fxProfile.setPreference("item", value);
```

The documentation for it is here. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html